# Why Methods can not be defined inside a method definition

Tags: java

If we can define a method inside "public static void main()" which is also a function why can't we do like this -

```
public void method_1()
{
      //statements 
        public void method_2()
               {
                        //statements
               }
}
```

Comment: You can't define a method inside `main`, which is a method.

Comment: why do you want to define method inside another method

Comment: You can't do either one without a lambda or inner class of somekind; what are you trying to actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Method` by its definition should belong to a class. You can have inner classes within a method and within innerclass you can have methods.

Comment: Although your statement is true, it doesn't explain as to why we can't (or mustn't) write methods inside of a method like Rudraksh intended.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's generally not a good idea to scope function A inside of function B. Otherwise only function B would be able to use function A. In this case, you would rather want to  use function A as a private method from a class anyways. If you wanted to do the opposite of this, making function A public would allow any method/function to use function A. Understanding the idea of having private and public methods/functions is enough to answer your question.